# Jinja2 block the Skeleton Framework's css

Tags: python, google-app-engine, templates, layout, jinja2

I am using Google App Engine with python to setup a simple web site. I found that the layout framework Skeleton is very simple to use and looks good. But the thing is it doesn't work with the Jinja2 template straight away. It seems that the Jinja2 hides the effect of the Skeleton.

How can I make the Skeleton work with the default GAE template?

Comment: After search around, i found the similar answer here:http://forums.udacity.com/questions/6012752/external-stylesheet-w-jinja2

Comment: It's just because the static file path problem.